# Move div down when parent div width changed

Tags: html, css

I have following page structure:

div_Menu  |  div_Stat1  div_Stat2  div_Stat3  div_Stat4

When page width is not enougth - 4 divs going under Menu div. If the width changed I want last div_Stat4 will go under div_Stat1.

Relevant part of the code:

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
<div class="action">
<div class="title">...</div>
<div class="stat">...</div>
<div class="stat">...</div>
<div class="stat">...</div>
<div class="stat">...</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menu {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #006666;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;
font-size: 2.0rem;
}
.action {
float: left;
padding-left: 60px;
}
.stat {
float: left;
background: #d8eacc;
padding: 10px;
border-color: azure;
border-style: solid;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;
font-size: 1.6rem;
width: 200px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

What should I change?

Correct display:

[image]

When browser width smaller:
[image]

Comment: What you are asking for is already happening with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your menu and content in a flexbox:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">...</div>
    <div class="action">
        <div class="title">...</div>
        <div class="stat">...</div>
        <div class="stat">...</div>
        <div class="stat">...</div>
        <div class="stat">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

That way, the `.action` will never go down.

Comment: I added parent div: .`stats {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 800px;
}`  When I changing width property - div moves well, but if I am changing browser width it's continue going down.

Comment: Can you create a snippet and explain what you mean by "continue going down"?

Comment: I added screenshots to post itself.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question then.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just interesting why id doesn't work when I wrapped only stat divs with parent flex?

Comment: Because flexbox is the context on its own, but it doesn't mean it stays where you want it to stay. It can still be too wide to fit and then it wraps.